# How do I manually specify the test files to run in autotest?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, autotest

How do I manually specify which test/unit test files should be run when a non-test file gets updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create custom mappings in `~/.autotest` or `<project_path>/.autotest` file like this:

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |at|
  at.add_mapping(/lib\/foo\/(.*).rb/, true) do |filename, matchdata|
    ["spec/lib/foo/#{matchdata[1]}_spec.rb"]
  end
end
```

This matches specs in `spec/lib/foo` directory to `lib/foo` files, so these specs will run once files under `lib/foo` are being changed. I guess you can do the same with `test` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Redefine `Autotest#test_files_for(filename)` to return an array of strings of the test file names.

Some tutorials refer to `tests_for_file`, but that was the old name of the method: it was [changed in ZenTest 3.9.0](http://www.zenspider.com/pipermail/ruby/2008-January/004115.html) to `test_files_for`.

Similarly, redefining `tests_files_for` won't help.